# How to include a sass file with given parameters

Tags: sass

I would like to use a 'default' sass code for my future templates, but the variables are not found. I'm looking for a way to pass variables to the layout file. I know that `@import` does not support parameters but I can't find another solution. See the code below for more information.

**green.scss**

```
$primary-color: #6ddba4;
$secondary-color: #6ddba4;
$tertiary-color: #6ddba4;

@import 'layout/layout.scss';
```

**layout.scss**

```
.home_icon {

    border: 1px solid $primary-color !important;
    color: $primary-color !important;

    &:hover {

        background-color: $secondary-color !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        border-color: #fff !important;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why not importing your variables inside `layout.scss`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SASS will look at all of your `.scss` files (and partials) and compile them together to an output `.css` file(s). As such, you cannot use JavaScript to directly manipulate SASS variables as they simply don't exist any more at the time the JavaScript is ran.

To get around this and achieve what you are wanting, you will need to have multiple stylesheets generated by SASS which you can then swap out with JavaScript.

It might look something like this:

**green.scss**

```
$primary-color: green;
$secondary-color: blue;
$tertiary-color: red;

@import "./layout";
```

**red.scss**

```
$primary-color: red;
$secondary-color: blue;
$tertiary-color: orange;

@import "./layout";
```

**_layout.scss**

```
.home_icon {
    border: 1px solid $primary-color !important;
    color: $primary-color !important;
    &:hover {
        background-color: $secondary-color !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        border-color: #fff !important;
    }
}

// Add as much as you want here and reference your variables
```

This will generate a `green.css` file and a `red.css` file which can then be swapped as needed in your HTML.

I've also stuck all of the above into a [working pen](https://codepen.io/andyusdigital/project/editor/DNbPLP) so that you can visualise it better and see the output CSS.

---

As a side note, [you can also assign CSS to variables which JavaScript can manipulate](https://medium.com/@_bengarrison/accessing-and-modifying-css-variables-with-javascript-2ccb735bbff0) however I don't think this is suitable in the use case that you have described. The option does exist though so pick whichever works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This way I have to copy the the base code into every template I create, because green.scss wil generate a css file which I will include trough JQuery.

Comment: I mean by base code the layout.scss file with all the needed classes which I can 'merge' with the a color file (green.scss, blue.scss). If I do it the other way around I have to copy al the base code (classes) inside every color file, so if I want to change something I have to change in much more files than only the layout.scss. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you're trying to do a lot better now. I've updated my answer with more details.

Comment: No problem, glad we got to the bottom of it!

Answer (score 0):

### You need to **@import 'green'**  to the layout.scss file

green.scss

```
$primary-color: #6ddba4;
$secondary-color: #6ddba4;
$tertiary-color: #6ddba4;
```

layout.scss

```
@import 'green'
    .home_icon {
    border: 1px solid $primary-color !important;
    color: $primary-color !important;
     &:hover {
        background-color: $secondary-color !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        border-color: #fff !important;
        }
    }
```

By doing this you can access all the variables present in green.scss to your layout.scss file.

Comment: Also thank your for you answer. It seems you have pretty much the same answer.